# Global vars in Codeigniter Module Class undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, global

I have the following piece of code in a codeigniter module controller:

```
class MyClass extends MX_Controller{
    public $description = "index";
    public function index(){
        global $description;
        echo $description;
    }
}
```

According to normal `PHP` rules and the `PHP` documentation, this should work. However, it doesn't.

If I leave out the `global $description` I get a notice about the variable being `undefined`, but with it in place it doesn't seem to return anything.

Why aren't `global variables` working in this case?

Comment: Globals are turned off, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: one way - you can set global variables in configuration file, and can use where ever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this instead of using global. 
This will work as you are in the scope of class
so you need `$this`

```
class MyClass extends MX_Controller{
    public $description = "index";
    public function index(){
        echo $this->description;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't explain why global vars in codeigniter don't work like global vars in vanilla PHP, but I'll set this as the accepted answer as it DOES give me a way to do what I wanted and is also vanilla PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables in this way:

```
$this->load->vars($global_variables_array);
```

where `$global_variables_array` is an associative key value pair array, description is:-

> This function takes an associative array as input and generates variables using the PHP extract function. This function produces the same result as using the second parameter of the $this->load->view() function above. The reason you might want to use this function independently is if you would like to set some global variables in the constructor of your controller and have them become available in any view file loaded from any function. You can have multiple calls to this function. The data get cached and merged into one array for conversion to variables.

[here is link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/loader.html)